# How does the back button work on Grooveshark?

Tags: jquery, hash

I recently started to use [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/). I noticed that although they have a dynamic interface in sense that you never leave the one page, but the back (and forward) buttons work anyway. If you press the button, only a part (think of a frame) of the content changes back to where you were, but the static elements of the interface stay. How do they manage that? Can you give me a trivial example?

Comment: This is what I found so far: http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2010/12/the-tech-behind-the-new-grooveshark/#jquery-hashchangehashchange

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript) tells you a way of spotting how the location has changed. According to that blog post they use a plugin for that. Basically it's a lot of clever javascript, with some flash for the player at the bottom.